# Can't cd into etc/profile, "not a directory"

Tags: 14.04, command-line, etc

I am new to Ubuntu (or any Linux distro) and I encountered a problem where I cannot **cd** into **etc/profile**. I was trying to edit the bashrc so that I could change the colours in my terminal window.

I tried to ls inside the **/etc/** file, and I see that there is a **profile** file there; but I can't enter it.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is not a directory, it is a file. There's an `/etc/profile.d` directory, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this fails is because `/etc/profile` is not a directory (unless you meant `/etc/profile.d`, but I don't think you did)

Instead use `gedit ~/.profile`
If you want to edit `.bashrc`: `gedit .bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

By default `/etc/profile` is not a folder but a file so you can't `cd` into it.

The global `bashrc` file is `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: I found the bash.bashrc file, but when I get down to the part where I am supposed to modify the colours, I see this:
`# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`

Comment: @gloriousCatnip if you want to modify colours, do that in your own `~/.bashrc`, not the system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: I nano'ed into ~/.bashrc, but it seems to be a copy of the aforementioned file.

Comment: @gloriousCatnip you'll see similarities, but they shouldn't be the same.

Comment: Hmm, nope. I can't find any settings regarding colour change. 
I followed a tutorial saying I should change the line proceeding this: `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then`
But there are no such lines in my bashrc, are there any way to reset it to its original content?